# USB stick connection

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter, mobile-broadband

I had purchased vodafone USB stick few months ago. At presently I am not using it, so I disconnected the connection and the dongle is there with me as it is. I tried to use other sim of other network company such as BSNL so it is showing me the gprs connection but I am not able to connect. The problem it is showing during the troubleshooting is VPN incorrect. So is there any thing that can be done to use vodafone dongle by putting BSNL sim ??? If yes please give me the steps....

Comment: did you change your APN? do the networks use the same sort of network?

Comment: In the network selection i changed the network to BSNL but then too it is showing VPN incorrect.

Comment: Did you uninstall the first adapter's software/drivers (might be causing some sort of conflict)?

Comment: I installed the software provided by vodafone.